# DocuSign TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT but document is attached (REST API)

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm using the DocuSign REST API to create an envelope from a template. My code works with single document templates or templates with multiple documents where only one document has tabs. If there are tabs on both documents I receive a 400 response with error code `TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT`.

The response I receive is:

```
{
  "error": "invalid HTTP response",
  "message": {
    "errorCode": "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",
    "message": "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 45159457 which is not present."
  },
  "status": 400,
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/2826983/envelopes/"
}
```

My request is as follows:

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "bb283bfb-4049-431d-942a-9a485e4ebb41", 
  "emailSubject": "[[Signer UserName]], please sign this document",
  "documents": [
     {
       "documentId": "27069418",
       "documentBase64": "...",
       "name": "name.pdf"
     },
     {
       "documentId": "45159457",
       "documentBase64": "...",
       "name": "secondName.pdf"
     }
   ]
}
```

From what I've seen people receive this request when they submit invalid documentId's like `1` but the document that's "missing" is clearly attached. Am I missing something?

---

The final and working JSON request looks like so:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "...",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": 2,
            "templateId": "..."
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": 1,
            "documents": [{
                "documentId": "...",
                "name": "...",
                "documentBase64": "..."
            }, {
                "documentId": "...",
                "name": "...",
                "documentBase64": "..."
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Why are you including the `documents` property in your request? Are you trying to replace the documents in the template?

Comment: Yes. I create a template, upload documents, and place tabs.

Afterwards, when using a single document, sending this request makes an envelope with the new document and keeps the tabs from the template document

Comment: Do your new documents have the same number of pages as the original document?

Comment: Yes, they're literally the same documents with some additional highlighting/text on them.

Comment: I believe composite templates are the only way you can accomplish your workflow, see CodingDawg's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome the error using [composite Templates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates). Specifying the new documents in an `inlineTemplate` with lower sequence number(`"sequence": "1"`) will ensure the `inlineTemplate` documents will replace the server template documents.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

```
{
    "emailSubject": "[[Signer UserName]], please sign this document",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "27069418",
                            "name": "name.pdf",
                            "documentBase64": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "documentId": "45159457",
                            "name": "secondName.pdf",
                            "documentBase64": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "templateId": "bb283bfb-4049-431d-942a-9a485e4ebb41"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. This results in an `"ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE"` error but it got me started in the right direction. 

Since I wanted to respect the signing order and tabs set in the template my request is as follows:

`{status: sent, emailSubject: "", compositeTemplates: [{serverTemplates: [{sequence: 1, templateId: ...}], inlineTemplates: [{sequence: 1, documents:[...]}]}`

Comment: @garfunkl3 did you ever get past the ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE issue?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the document(s) in a template you must use composite templates instructions in your Envelopes: create call.

In your use case, you want to composite together the template and then a new document "in front" of the existing document in the template.

"Compositing templates" is like [compositing together multiple pieces of film to produce a final print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing).